# What is the right way to use QQuickImageProvider?

Tags: c++, image, qt, qml

I need to select dynamically qpixmaps to display inside QML Image items. That qpixmaps should be cropped from the source qpixmap, which I'm going to set from the QML file. I'd like them to be cropped by C++ code on the first demand from QML and to be cached for the future use. For dynamical images manipulating it's ought to derive my own class from QQuickImageProvider and load it to QML Application engine. But how can I control the source qpixmap then? Via property? If yes, then my custom provider must be derived from QObject and it's instance should be declared inside QML, isn't it? But how can it be loaded by the engine then? I feel that this way of implementing is wrong, but which one would be correct?

UPD: Ok, I have a class:

```
class MyQuickImageProvider : public QQuickImageProvider {
public:
    ...
    // This method should set the source image path
    void setPath ( QUrl path );
    // Overriden method of base class; should return cropped image
    virtual QPixmap requestPixmap ( const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize );
    ...
}
```

In main.cpp it's loaded as:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
...
engine.addImageProvider("my_quick_image_provider", new MyQuickImageProvider(QQmlImageProviderBase::Image));
```

I'd like to change source image path via QML. How can I make setPath method accessible to it? The obvious way is to declare the method as Q_INVOKABLE (and derive MyQuickImageProvider from QObject and qmlRegisterType it), but then I should declare the instance of my class within the QML source:

```
MyQuickImageProvider {
    id: my_quick_image_provider
    ...
}
```

The access to it from main.cpp will be problematic. And such a design seems weird to me. Is there any more elegant solution?

Comment: The question is quite confusing to me. What is the actual problem you're encountering? What does your code look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not use `MyQuickImageProvider` as an QML object, nor do you define a `Q_INVOKABLE` method because you cannot access the image provider object from QML.

`engine.addImageProvider("my_quick_image_provider", [...]`

sets the name how you access images, e.g.

```
// qml file
Image {
    source: "image://my_quick_image_provider/name_of_my_image"
}
```

The later part "name_of_my_image" is called the `id`, which you find in

```
virtual QPixmap requestPixmap ( const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize );
```

Now implement `requestPixmap` in your `MyQuickImageProvider` and let it use the `id` string to produce a QPixmap.

I think you can throw away the `void setPath ( QUrl path );` method because you only need one image provider instance for all images of that kind.

Since constructors are not inherited from the base class, I don't think  `new MyQuickImageProvider(QQmlImageProviderBase::Image));` makes sense. Better add a constructor with no argument

```
class MyQuickImageProvider : public QQuickImageProvider {
public:
    MyQuickImageProvider();
    // ...
```

and have the image type in your initializer list:

```
MyQuickImageProvider::MyQuickImageProvider()
    : QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Pixmap)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Simon! As I understand, this algorithm will require to check whether the source image changed on every requestPixmap call (while setPath would allow to avoid check every time). Cannot this be optimized?

Comment: QML does cache the pixmap of an `Image` for a given `image://` url for you, so it assumes that the underlying image does not change frequently. Where do you get the images from? If you already have a method that informs you when an image changed, use signals/slots to pass that information to your image provider. But you should put that into a follow-up question as soon as you got the basics right.

Comment: I have source image ("big") loaded from file and qhash of small images; every small image is "lazily" cropped from big one and is put to qhash, when it's id is requested for the first time. So I need to change small images frequently, while big one—much less frequently. Now I'm going to control big image file name via property.

Answer (score 0):

Created and tested in Qt-6.2.4

**main.cpp** - with default Qt code except line **engine.addImageProvider("colors", new test);**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "test.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.addImageProvider("colors", new test);

    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/qimgprovider/main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);
    return app.exec();
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"

test::test() : QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Pixmap)
{ 
}
    
QPixmap test::requestPixmap(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
   int width = 100;
   int height = 50;
   if (size)
      *size = QSize(width, height);
   QPixmap pixmap(requestedSize.width() > 0 ? requestedSize.width() : width,
                  requestedSize.height() > 0 ? requestedSize.height() : height);
   pixmap.fill(QColor(id).rgba());
   return pixmap;
}
```

**test.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QQuickImageProvider>

class test : public QQuickImageProvider
{
public:
    test();
    QPixmap requestPixmap(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize) override;
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Glory to Ukraine!")
    Column {
        Image { source: "image://colors/blue" }
        Image { source: "image://colors/yellow" }
    }
}
```

Comment: qimgprovider is qt project name